# Android toggle button click set textview

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I wanted to set a textview on click of toggle button. when toggle button is clicked there is length operation method is being called so before that I wanted to set a textview saying "service is starting" but I have noticed that the textview is being set once the toggle button state changes from START to STOP and after the method call completes.

Can you help me to show the textview before method call.

I have coped the code below.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Reader.getInstance(this,this);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        startMyService();
                    }
                };
                t.start();

                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);                   

            }
            else {

                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        stopMyService();
                    }
                };
                t.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks.

I have used the below code but on click of toggle button nothing is showed up. I have tried putting the lengthy code inside a thread but the method did not execute even after after using thread.join .

Comment: post full code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    class startservice_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            startMyService();
            return null;
        }
    }





toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                startservice_AsyncTask startserviceTask = new startservice_AsyncTask();
                startserviceTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
            else {

                Thread t = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        stopMyService();
                    }
                };
                t.start();
            }
        }
    });
```